# Using Preapproval key for paypal transaction without user authentication

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

i have successfully generated Preapproval key by making necessary api call.
I need to know how to execute the payment with this Preapproval key so that user authentication is not required.
i need the php code for making this payrequest api call

Comment: what have you tried so far to code? First give it a try and ask then for a specific coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to Step 2 on [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/)

```
// $approvalKey should be your previously retrieved Approval Key
// Change  sandbox to the production URL for LIVE mode
$ppRedirectUrl  = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=' . $approvalKey;

header('Location:' . $ppRedirectUrl );
exit();
```